# My [fieldObject].ApplyFont(fontname) is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to set a font for a field object in crystal reports in c# using the font that I embedded in resources folder

```
`FieldObject field;
field = oRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["CouponCode3"] as FieldObject;
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile("~/Resources/IDAutomationHC39M.ttf");

unsafe
{
   fixed (byte* pFontData = Properties.Resources.IDAutomationHC39M)
   {
       uint dummy = 0;
       pfc.AddMemoryFont((IntPtr)pFontData, Properties.Resources.IDAutomationHC39M.Length);
       AddFontMemResourceEx((IntPtr)pFontData, (uint)Properties.Resources.IDAutomationHC39M.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
   }
}

Font barcodeFont = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 12);
field.ApplyFont(barcodeFont);`
```

Comment: Is the font installed on the machine?

Comment: I don't think it's going to work unless the font is installed on the machine.

Comment: nope, i'm trying to use the font i have embedded in my solution.      fyi, I'm developing a windows form app

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're using IDAutomation's barcode? Have you followed their installation instructions for using the font in a windows form?

1. Download and unzip the package into a directory on the development computer.
2. Copy the DLL that is to be used to the project directory. Do not copy the components to the bin directory; upon compiling the project, the DLL in the project folder will be copied to the appropriate bin folder with the associated EXE file automatically.
3. The application must be able to access the control after it is installed from a local drive for security purposes. Examples are provided below that should help with the various methods of using and printing the images.

Source [here](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-components/windows-forms-control/user-manual.html).